# Disk space visualizer with delete function

Tags: disk-space, disk-cleanup

Is there a tool that let me (recursively) visualize how much diskspace space directories and files (!) consume on my disk and that lets me delete directories and files (!) which would result in a on the fly update of the visualization. Something like [HDGraph](http://www.hdgraph.com/) only that it also shows the size of the files separately and that it has a delete function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SpaceSniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/index.html) brings up the standard Windows context menu on a right-click, so yes, it can delete.

It updates instantly as well (even from things outside the application, which is awesome to watch!)

Comment: This is the best answer because SpaceSniffer ist fast (you don't have to wait until the whole disk is scanned, it updated automatically when something changes (even through external applications) plus it has the best search, filter and tagging functionality of all suggested apps. Also the UI is comparably sleek and modern.

Answer (score 4):

I found WinDirStat a while back and found it to be awesome. You can delete files from within the application. You can also do it outside and then right-click any part of the directory tree and have it refresh it quickly.

http://windirstat.info/

Answer (score 1):

[TreeSize](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) does it very well, and the pro version has a nice pie chart and bar chart - if the starburst chart of the alternate tools is not your taste.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly use the excellent freeware [Folder Scanner](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/).